# Haskell Sqlite 3 triggers - Syntax error

Tags: sqlite, haskell, syntax, triggers, syntax-error

I've written a simple trigger using HDBC and Sqlite3.

calculateNoOfStocksTraded::Database.HDBC.Sqlite3.Connection->IO Integer
calculateNoOfStocksTraded conn=do

```
                           run conn "CREATE TRIGGER calStocks\
                           \AFTER INSERT ON historicalData\
                           \FOR EACH ROW\
                           \BEGIN\
                           \UPDATE company\
                           \SET noOfStocks=300.0;\
                           \END " []
```

It keeps saying that there's a syntax error. I don't know how to figure it out. pls help me to locate the error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pieces of your SQL strings are being run together without spaces between them (because that's how the string breaks with `\` work in Haskell). Try adding a space at the end of each line of the query, before the `\`.